# bash find unique lines in a file

Tags: bash, shell

I have to search for unique lines in a text file, however there is an additional tweak. I need to consider as duplicates the lines which have the first part (separated by a dot) equal.
For example:

```
DEASLR98
DEASLR98.acme.it
```

These lines are equal, however

```
sort file.txt | uniq
```

Includes them both. Any suggestion how to include just the line with full domain info (e.g. DEASLR98.acme.it) ?
Thanks!

Comment: If there are `DEASLR98.foo.bar` and `DEASLR98.example.com`, which one should win?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple Awk `uniq` implementation which keeps the longest match for each key.

```
awk -F . '!($1 in a) || length(a[$1]) < length($0) { a[$1] = $0 }
    END { for (k in a) print a[k] }' file.txt
```

The `-F .` instructs Awk to split each input line on dots.  Thus `$1` contains the field before the first dot.  If this field is missing from the array `a`, or the line is longer than the existing value for this key, we keep the whole input line (`$0`) in the array.  At the end, we print out the values in the array.  This will obviously require the array to fit into memory.